# Nautilus is extremely slow

Tags: 11.04, nautilus

I am on Ubuntu 11.04. And Nautilus is very slow. It opens directories for 3-5 seconds even if a directory contains just a few small files. Even selecting of a file or directory with narrow keys is extremely slow and it rises my CPU usage up to 100%.
It makes it almost unusable.

But I noticed that if I start my nautilus as superuser:

```
$ gksu nautilus
```

then it works just fine. It is fast and responsive.

So what can I do to fix this?
Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I fould this on http://subbass.blogspot.com/2009/05/is-your-nautilus-slow-to-open.html

> Is your Nautilus slow to open directories?
>
> Fix Naultilus slow loading some directories.
>
> If nautilus is taking an age to load some directories on your computer
>   then you may have Assistive Technologies enabled.
>
> Simply go to the System menu on your desktop and then in Preferences.
>   Click on Assistive Technologies.Untick the box marked "Enable
>   Assistive Technologies" and choose "Close and Log Out" at the bottom
>   of the window.

Answer (score 0):

I found this bug report on Launchpad that now has expired; in the comments someone told that the problem can be related to the nautilus dropbox plugin, but I don't know if this is the case.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/776781

Answer (score 0):

Switching the directory view from *detailed* to *compact* made a big difference for me on Lucid.